# cannot display array values in ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

```
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost/abc/all-data.php',
                data: {
                    data1: "1"},
                    success: function(response)
                           {
                        alert(response);
                        }          
            });
            return false;
```

I want to display each element of array one by one in success function of the ajax currently i get all elements to gether

this is my php code

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $qry )){

$temp[$i]['c_n'] = $row['c_name'];
$temp[$i]['j_t'] = $row['Job_Title'];
$temp[$i]['des'] = $row['description'];
$temp[$i]['req'] = $row['requirments'];
$temp[$i]['dat'] = $row['posted'];

$i++;
}
$data = array('temp'=> $temp);
echo JSON_encode($temp);
```

I do appreciate your helps

Answer (score 2):

you probably use something like this in your success function :

```
   response.temp.forEach(function(element){
         console.log(element.c_n) ;
         console.log(element.j_t) ;
         console.log(element.des) ;
         console.log(element.req) ; 
         console.log(element.dat) ;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your success function, you need to json parse your response

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

You can access to your data:
`data['temp']`

If you want your response parsed to json automaticallym you can setup your ajax settings like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

Then you don't need to call JSON.parse anymore.

Comment: when i use JSON.parse and alert(data['temp']); it display undefined

Comment: @Ahmad please actually show us the code you've used. Simply saying something doesn't work, or shows undefined is useless as it's possible you're not using the method correctly

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` print ?

Comment: success: function(response)
                   {
             var data = JSON.parse(response);
             alert(data['temp']);
             //console.log(data);
                }

Comment: @Ahmad Okay and what about `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: Do you know how to open your web browser console ? Ctrl+Shift+J on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$i=0;  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
  $temp[$i]['c_n'] = $row['c_name'];
  $temp[$i]['j_t'] = $row['Job_Title'];
  $temp[$i]['des'] = $row['description'];
  $temp[$i]['req'] = $row['requirments'];
  $temp[$i]['dat'] = $row['posted'];
  $i++;
}      $data = array('temp'=> $temp);   echo JSON_encode($temp);
```

Please change the last line as 
`return JSON_encode($data);`

Hope this helps you :)